# Prolog: How to convert hexadecimal value to integer in Prolog

Tags: prolog, hex

Prolog: How to convert hexadecimal value to integer in Prolog

My input value is `0x10` and I want to increment it in Prolog.

```
increment(_incremented_value) :-
  _my_var= 0x10,
  _incremented_value is _my_var + 1.
```

but this is giving error, saying `_my_var` is not integer

Comment: Your code runs without problems. My answer was stupid and now is removed. Your question should be edited to be a real question or removed.

Comment: How to convert hexadecimal value to integer in Prolog?

Comment: "How to convert hexadecimal value to integer in Prolog?" Good question. What do you mean? Or is your comment by mistake?

Comment: @User9213: my question is nothing but answer to your query, as you were not getting my main query. Prolog is language and in that language I want to convert hexadecimal value into integer value...anything else u want to make u clear

Comment: An integer is an integer. It has nothing to do with how you write it. You don't need to convert it, for sure. In normal computer architectures, in languages from the C pedigree, integers are represented internally in binary. You also have some more exotic stuff like numbers in Oracle DB, which are normally represented as strings of digits. In addition, you claim you have a problem but I can run the code in your question, so your question makes no sense, but I tried to answer it anyway.

Comment: About integers/numbers as strings of digits, I suspect `dc` does something similar. I am too lazy to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't convert anything, Prolog understand hexadecimal literals. By default it prints integers in base 10, so you get:

```
?- X = 0x10.
X = 16.

?- X = 0xAB.
X = 171.
```

You can use formatted printing to print the integer in any base you like. In SWI-Prolog:

```
?- X = 0xFF, format("~2r", [X]).
11111111
X = 255.

?- X = 0xFF, format("~36r", [X]).
73
X = 255.

?- X = 3, format("~3r", [X]).
10
X = 3.
```

If you are asking something else you should make it clear what it is.

Comment: ohh great let me try this succ predicate

Comment: @User9213: `_my_var` is a valid prolog variable. Depending on which Prolog interpreter you are using, the interpreter may not issue singleton warnings for variables which start with an underscore and are not used elsewhere.